# Get the value from Rest post API

Tags: php, rest

Output when success

> string(66)
>   "{"status":true,"message":"success","data":{"amountDue":"-504.20"}}"

Output when error

> string(119) "{"status":false,"message":"An error occured while getting
>   full subscriber profile: Subscription not found MPP servers"}"

How should I write in php to get the amount due from the output? I am new to REST api. Can someone show me ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a JSON-encoded response. Use json_decode() to convert the string back into an array, and then access the array element:

```
$output = '{"status":true,"message":"success","data":{"amountDue":"-504.20"}}';
$results = json_decode($output,true);

if($results["status"])
{
  echo "Success! Data: " . print_r($results,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can at least send proper request to the endpoint and you are able to capture the response.

You receive a json string which must be parses so if:

```
$response = '{"status":true,"message":"success","data":{"amountDue":"-504.20"}}';
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
```

Then you will get a responseArray as associated array (the second parameter) so you can get amount due like that

```
$amountDue = $responseArray['data']['amountDue'];
```

You could also parse json data into an StdClass which turn all fields in json into an object's property. To do that abandon the second parameter in json_decode function

```
$resultObj = json_decode($response);
$amountDue = $resultObj->data['amountDue'];
```

All depends on your requests.
To read more about json_decode try [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)